# How to span a table in a multi-columned layout in XSL-FO?

Tags: xsl-fo

How to make `fo:table` to span across two columns? I have tried to wrap it into `<fo:block span="all">` but that does not work. Is it possible at all?

Comment: You need to show your code and also specify what product you are using. Certainly it is possible, perhaps your code is not exactly correct or the product you are using does not support it. Like perhaps in the fo:block an immediate child of fo:flow?

Comment: Please familiarize yourself with the format we require questions to be in on Stackoverflow. Above all, you must give a _reproducible_ example of your problem, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Show a complete, minimal XSL-FO document (or XML and XSLT) and show the output you expect (here, not in an off-site link). If your question contains "does not work", you need to tell us _what_ does not work.

Comment: Sure, thanks for guidance. However, sometimes it is not easy to reproduce an error from a really complex solution. This is not the case here, sorry for not sticking to the best practices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So using this code:

```
      <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
    <fo:block>Feugiat erat sit justo takimata lorem diam sed. Quis tempor hendrerit aliquyam eum invidunt labore. Ipsum delenit clita lorem. Sed ea sit et labore tempor clita no aliquyam sed clita lorem et. Dolor lorem ipsum et est sit dolores diam gubergren ut feugait ea ea magna. Eos duo consetetur eu et tempor invidunt eos dolore dolore ut ea aliquyam duis gubergren. Ea sed tempor kasd magna et nonumy sed dolore et stet diam takimata et. Placerat magna wisi. Gubergren duo luptatum dolore veniam dolores magna et consetetur dolor volutpat invidunt.</fo:block>
    <fo:block>Elitr consetetur tempor nulla adipiscing erat vero erat ipsum ut labore elitr feugiat dolor et sit kasd labore molestie. Amet sit lorem amet amet lorem amet labore delenit nonumy doming erat ut diam. Et et rebum. Ut justo magna ipsum lorem duis justo invidunt labore amet ipsum diam vulputate vel accusam. Clita nibh sed dolore ea dolor vero amet magna diam eirmod sea kasd erat consetetur stet. Dolor amet diam justo eos. Aliquyam tempor rebum ea et et. No consetetur stet lorem sanctus quis sed et amet eirmod amet et ea exerci. Gubergren nulla sanctus sanctus justo sadipscing sit lobortis eu ea. Kasd elit velit takimata magna.</fo:block>
    <fo:block span="all">
      <fo:table width="100%">
        <fo:table-body>
          <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell border="1pt solid black"><fo:block>I am a table</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell border="1pt solid black"><fo:block>I am a table</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell border="1pt solid black"><fo:block>I am a table</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell border="1pt solid black"><fo:block>I am a table</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
          </fo:table-row>
          <fo:table-row>
            <fo:table-cell border="1pt solid black"><fo:block>I am a table</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell border="1pt solid black"><fo:block>I am a table</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell border="1pt solid black"><fo:block>I am a table</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
            <fo:table-cell border="1pt solid black"><fo:block>I am a table</fo:block></fo:table-cell>
          </fo:table-row>
        </fo:table-body>
      </fo:table>
    </fo:block>
    <fo:block>Dolore eu kasd sed sea vero dolor accusam ea takimata erat amet dolore quis consetetur sit et tempor. Nulla eum aliquyam mazim accumsan feugiat et elitr duis dolore tempor nonumy sanctus lobortis lorem consequat hendrerit aliquam. Justo magna laoreet et sed eros et molestie sadipscing ut dolor euismod sed et accusam dolore hendrerit. Vero clita dolore vel dolore ipsum sed ullamcorper dolores eos. Voluptua sadipscing soluta sit ut invidunt sed est aliquyam diam ea. Gubergren erat facilisi rebum sit invidunt lorem ut labore gubergren no soluta. Amet illum amet vel euismod lorem ullamcorper et sit liber et et clita sanctus ut dolor.</fo:block>
    <fo:block>Esse elitr dolor est iusto exerci magna sed qui lorem eirmod eirmod duis illum sit. Duo velit kasd et magna est et ipsum dolore elitr lorem magna sea nulla diam at clita aliquam. Consetetur aliquyam augue clita sea sit labore accusam. Magna vero gubergren placerat dolore consetetur est duis sit takimata dignissim aliquyam dolores et iusto. Gubergren mazim praesent est stet vel diam diam sed laoreet iusto odio vero. Vero justo dolores magna dolore feugait dolore takimata lorem ea vero assum vero lorem lorem nostrud diam takimata. Feugiat dolores laoreet enim lorem. Et dolor et enim et laoreet ut sadipscing amet dolore erat at invidunt vulputate dolor dolores invidunt. Ipsum aliquyam mazim sea voluptua sed et eirmod rebum stet elitr labore dignissim. Invidunt dolore lorem at et kasd sanctus exerci velit</fo:block>
    <fo:block>Feugiat erat sit justo takimata lorem diam sed. Quis tempor hendrerit aliquyam eum invidunt labore. Ipsum delenit clita lorem. Sed ea sit et labore tempor clita no aliquyam sed clita lorem et. Dolor lorem ipsum et est sit dolores diam gubergren ut feugait ea ea magna. Eos duo consetetur eu et tempor invidunt eos dolore dolore ut ea aliquyam duis gubergren. Ea sed tempor kasd magna et nonumy sed dolore et stet diam takimata et. Placerat magna wisi. Gubergren duo luptatum dolore veniam dolores magna et consetetur dolor volutpat invidunt.</fo:block>
    <fo:block>Feugiat erat sit justo takimata lorem diam sed. Quis tempor hendrerit aliquyam eum invidunt labore. Ipsum delenit clita lorem. Sed ea sit et labore tempor clita no aliquyam sed clita lorem et. Dolor lorem ipsum et est sit dolores diam gubergren ut feugait ea ea magna. Eos duo consetetur eu et tempor invidunt eos dolore dolore ut ea aliquyam duis gubergren. Ea sed tempor kasd magna et nonumy sed dolore et stet diam takimata et. Placerat magna wisi. Gubergren duo luptatum dolore veniam dolores magna et consetetur dolor volutpat invidunt.</fo:block>
    <fo:block>Feugiat erat sit justo takimata lorem diam sed. Quis tempor hendrerit aliquyam eum invidunt labore. Ipsum delenit clita lorem. Sed ea sit et labore tempor clita no aliquyam sed clita lorem et. Dolor lorem ipsum et est sit dolores diam gubergren ut feugait ea ea magna. Eos duo consetetur eu et tempor invidunt eos dolore dolore ut ea aliquyam duis gubergren. Ea sed tempor kasd magna et nonumy sed dolore et stet diam takimata et. Placerat magna wisi. Gubergren duo luptatum dolore veniam dolores magna et consetetur dolor volutpat invidunt.</fo:block>
  </fo:flow>
```

I get this with testing Apache FOP and RenderX XEP:

[image]

This shows the table spans both columns in a two column document.

Comment: Thanks for the hint with `fo:flow`, it really needs to have the block as a child of it, then it works!